# In tmux, can I get `exit` to exit the containing terminal window and not the session itself?

Tags: linux, bash, terminal, tmux

So when I open a new terminal (I use terminator on Arch Linux), I have it configured to either  open a new `tmux` session if one doesn't exist, or attach to an existing one. When I type `exit` at the prompt, it quits the tmux session. I have to type `exit` again to quit the terminal. What I want is that typing `exit` once will quit the terminal, but leave `tmux` running, so the next time I open the terminal it will reattach to the previous `tmux` session. Essentially, this is the equivalent of clicking the exit button for the window manager, but I want this functionality when typing `exit`.

EDIT:

This is something like what I want:

```
alias exit='if [[ $TMUX = "" ]]; then exit; else tmux detach; exit; fi'
```

but the issue is the `exit` after the `tmux detach` should get called in the terminal containing the tmux session, not the tmux session itself.

Comment: please elaborate how exactly you "have it configured to either open a new tmux session if one doesn't exist, or attach to an existing one"

Comment: @lesmana I was just providing context. How that's configured it completely irrelevant to the question. You can imagine I don't even have that configured, and the question would be the same.

Comment: `exit` is not a `tmux` command; it's a shell command. `tmux` only exits if you terminate the command (usually, a shell) in the last pane of the last window. It sounds like you just want to detach from the current session, in which case you should use the appropriate `tmux` command or key binding.

Comment: @chepner, I know `exit` isn't a tmux command. I want to detach from the session and exit the terminal (not the session), but I want to use the `exit` command in a tmux session to do that. I think it should be possible with some bash-fu.

Comment: Why? You're trying to override the shell built-in `exit` to *not* exit a shell. Anyway, as long as you have `tmux` be the *actual* command that the terminal runs (as opposed to starting `tmux` as a child of a shell started by the terminal), detaching will cause the last program running in the shell to exit and, assuming your terminal is configured to do so, automatically close the window.

Comment: @chepner I'm trying to override so that if it is not a tmux session, it exits normally, and if it is a tmux session, it exits the shell containing the tmux session.

Answer (score 5):

We have to declare two functions one to start tmux and the other to exit tmux :

```
function ttmux {
  if (pgrep tmux); then
    tmux attach
  else 
    tmux
  fi
  builtin exit
}
```

This will execute either (tmux attach or tmux) if tmux process existed or not , after you finish using tmux , built-in exit will be executed to close the terminal(if there isn't nested shell).

```
function exit {
  if [ ${TMUX} ]; then
      tmux detach
  else 
      builtin exit
  fi
}
```

If you inside tmux will detach it , if not will execute built-in exit

Put them in your .bashrc or .zshrc  and change function name if you wish, and call them.

```
>> ttmux # to start tmux
>> exit # to detach tmux
```

Comment: Follow-up: is it possible for this exist function to detect panes and not exit? If so, how?

Answer (score 0):

```
terminator -e tmux
```

this will start terminator with tmux running instead of a shell. if the tmux process exits terminator will close right after.

Comment: Right, but typing `exit` will still kill the final terminal and exit tmux, right?